# Gems not installed by bundle install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, bundler

After clearing out my gems with `rvm gemset empty`, I re-installed rails (3.2.13) and then deleted my `Gemfile.lock` and ran `bundle install`. Bundler doesn't installed gems, it just says it's "using" them as if they're already installed. So when I try to run the app, I'm told "Could not find [gem namne] in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)".

**Edit:** I was running `sudo bundle install` because one of the gems is installed from a local source. When using `sudo`, the gems are not installed. When just running `bundle install`, Bundler does try to install the missing gems but it can't install the `bootstrap-sass` gem which is coming from a local source.

**Gemfile**

```
source "https://rubygems.org"

gem "rails", "~> 3.2.13"
gem "mysql2", "~> 0.3.13"
gem "json", "~> 1.8.0"

group :assets do
  gem "guard-rails-assets", "~> 0.1.3"
  gem "sass-rails", "~> 3.2.6"
  gem "coffee-rails", "~> 3.2.2"
  gem "uglifier", "~> 1.0.3"
end

gem "jquery-rails", "~> 3.0.4"
gem "simple_form", "~> 2.1.0"
gem "bootstrap-sass", :path => "gems/bootstrap-sass-c0e12a90ba3e"
gem "client_side_validations", "~> 3.2.6"
gem "client_side_validations-simple_form", "~> 2.1.0"
gem "therubyracer", :platform => :ruby
gem "require_relative", "~> 1.0.3"
gem "icalendar", "~> 1.4.3"
gem "whenever", "~> 0.8.4", :require => false
gem "jquery-cookie-rails", "~> 1.3.1"
gem "hominid", "~> 3.0.5"
```

**`gem list`**

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

actionmailer (3.2.13)
actionpack (3.2.13)
activemodel (3.2.13)
activerecord (3.2.13)
activeresource (3.2.13)
activesupport (3.2.13)
arel (3.0.3)
builder (3.0.4)
bundler (1.5.2)
bundler-unload (1.0.2)
daemon_controller (1.1.8)
erubis (2.7.0)
executable-hooks (1.3.1)
gem-wrappers (1.2.4)
hike (1.2.3)
i18n (0.6.1)
journey (1.0.4)
json (1.8.1)
mail (2.5.4)
mime-types (1.25.1)
multi_json (1.8.4)
passenger (4.0.35)
polyglot (0.3.3)
rack (1.4.5)
rack-cache (1.2)
rack-ssl (1.3.3)
rack-test (0.6.2)
rails (3.2.13)
railties (3.2.13)
rake (10.1.1)
rdoc (3.12.2)
rubygems-bundler (1.4.2)
rvm (1.11.3.8)
sprockets (2.2.2)
thor (0.18.1)
tilt (1.4.1)
treetop (1.4.15)
tzinfo (0.3.38)
```

Why isn't `bundle` installing the gems in my Gemfile?

Comment: Which `bundle` are you using? I mean, what does `which bundle` return?

Comment: @MarekLipka - `/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374@global/bin/bundle`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run `sudo bundle install` you're probably using a different instance of bundler (either you have another instance of RVM installed globally for your system, or you're just using the default system ruby)

As a result, it will install the gems for that system ruby. If you later open the server without using `sudo` it will look for the gems in your local RVM, which does not have the
Installing with just ``` ``bundle install ``` is the correct way. What you should do instead is fix that path error from bootstrap-sass. Which, by the way, is probably occuring because of the same problem
You probably have a path `"gems/bootstrap-sass-c0e12a90ba3e"` in your system ruby, but not on your local RVM

Answer (score 1):

I guess you should put your version of `bootstrap-sass` gem in directory available without root privileges.